# Combine array of keys and array of values into object

Tags: javascript

I have an array with labels

```
columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
```

and thousands of arrays with values

```
values = [ 
    ['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
    ['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
    ['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
    // ...
]
```

I want to iterate the values and create a single array with this structure:

```
result = [ 
    { col1: "val1", col2: "val2", col3: "val3", col3: "val4" },
    { col1: "val1", col2: "val2", col3: "val3", col3: "val4" },
    { col1: "val1", col2: "val2", col3: "val3", col3: "val4" },
]
```

I tried to iterate both and return the object dynamically, but without success:

```js
const columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];
const values = [ 
    ['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
    ['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
    ['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
];

const lastArr = values.map((e) =>
    columns.map((col) => {
        return { col: e[0] };
    })
);

console.log(lastArr);

// or manually 

const raw = values.map(e => 
    columns.map(col => {
        return {
            col1: e[0],
            col2: e[1],
            col3: e[2],
            col4: e[3],
        }
    })
);

console.log(raw);
```

Neither attempts return the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more understandable if your examples were more consistent and the values were a bit more distinguishable but this should do the trick

```
values.map(v => Object.fromEntries(columns.map((c,i) => [c, v[i]])));
```

Comment: you forget a final ] bracket : values.map(v => Object.fromEntries(columns.map((c,i) => [c, v[i]])));

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.fromEntries`, like so:

```js
const columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
const values = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12]
];

const result = values.map(row =>
    Object.fromEntries(columns.map((col, i) =>
        [col, row[i]]
    ))
)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditional JS way to use `.reduce()` to transform array to new array (form).

Inner part loop to iterate the `column` array and current iterated item of `values`, and next add as key-value pair into an object.

```js
let columns = ["col1",
    "col2",
    "col3",
    "col4"
]

let values = [
    ['value1', 'value2'],
    ['value1', 'value2'],
    ['value1', 'value2']
]

let result = values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    let obj = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
    {
        obj[columns[i]] = cur[i];
    }

    acc.push(obj);

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```